# Can a foreign key change its value over time?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So I am trying to create a MySQL database of basketball players and to track their performance over time. I have a table TEAM with a "id" as its primary key. Also I have a table PLAYER that has "team_id" as its foreign key referencing id field from the TEAM table.

My question is if a player changes a team will it be possible to change value of the team id field?

Comment: Hi! This is possible in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - yes, it is. As long as you change the player's team id to another valid team id, this is just a straight-forward update statement:

```sql
UPDATE player
SET    team_id = 123 -- the new team
WHERE  id = 456 -- the player's id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the "team_id" value but the new value should be a primary key of TEAM table.